# project compiles from git but not as new in Xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode

I downloaded a sample project from github. https://github.com/dev5tec/FBMediaViewer

I then did a build/compile and it worked just fine in Xcode 6

I then created a brand new test project called 009_test1 in Xcode 6. dragged and dropped all the files from FBMediaViewer into my sample project. Now when I compile I get this error.

[image]
[image]
[image]

For the life of me I cannot figure out why am I getting this error now when the original project compiles just fine with no errors. I tried comparining all the build setting between my new and FBMediaViewer project but nothing seem to stand out. Note, there is not a single piece of custom code I had added so far.  Is this a bug with Xcode 6? Is there some setting that is screwed up when a new project is created from scratch?

I had an old Xcode 5 project where I had used FBMediaViewer before. So I opened it in Xcode 6 and it also compiled fine. I mean what the $!@#%!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import UIKit. `@import UIKit;`

Comment: Custom classes that extend NSObject don't import UIKit by default since oftentimes they don't need to. You're welcome!